# jQuery event is not getting fired every time

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with the `.toggle()` function that I am using. I am getting results from a database using PHP and filling a table with the information. The last item in each table row is a link, that when clicked should show another row that allows an admin to edit the information for that product. The link's class is `.edit_prod` Here is my jQuery method:

```
$(function() {
$(".edit_prod").click(function() {
 $("#mydiv").toggle();
      return false;
     });
 });
```

Can someone help me out on what could possibly be going wrong?

Thanks!

Update:

Here is the PHP code which creates the HTML

```
$table_format = sprintf("
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='%s' id='edit_img_pic' />
            </td>
            <td>
                %s
            </td>
            <td>
                %s
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class='edit_prod' href='#'>Edit</a>  
            </td>



        </tr>
        <tr id='mydiv' style='display: none' cellspacing='20px'>
            <form action='edit_product.php' method='post'>
            <td>
                <label for='name'>Product Name</label><br>
                <input type='text' name='name' value='%s' /><br><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for='sku'>SKU</label><br>
                <input type='text' name='sku' value='%s' /><br><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for='price'>Price</label><br>
                $<input type='text' name='price' value='%s' /><br><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for='desc'>Description</label><br>
                <textarea cols='40' rows='7' name='desc'></textarea><br><br>
                <input type='submit' value='Save' />
            </form>
        <tr>
        ", $img, $prod_name, $sku, $prod_name, $sku, $price);

        echo $table_format;
```

Update 2:

Comment: "each table" implies that there's more than one but you're accessing by id?

Comment: Could you produce a fiddle with this happening?

Comment: Your code is [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/zuUQn/), something else is going on in your DOM.

Comment: what issues are you seeing? even before your edit to make it class="mydiv", clicking the "Edit" link definitely toggled open the hidden rows and clicking again made them hide. Obviously, now that it's toggling the class, it will open all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your last sentence

> each table row is a link, that when clicked should show another row
>   that allows an admin to edit the information

Seems that you are dynamically loading elements to your html, that way the new elements have no click event attached to them because you probably attach it on `document.Ready()`..

jQuery has a "on" API that you could use to attach click events to DOM elements loaded dynamically.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @rockerest.. changed from using `live()` to `on()` and corrected according to @Sly_cardinal.

Try something like that:

```
$(function() {
    $("table").on("click", ".edit_prod", function() {
        $("#mydiv").toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jQuery on API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If you're using anything newer than 1.7, don't use `.live`, since it's deprecated.  Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @Mortalus could you happen to give me a demo on how to do the document.ready event attaching please? Haven't done that before. Thanks

Comment: @MattAltepeter your code `$(function(){` is a shortcut for binding on `document.ready`.

Comment: As of right now, there are only two products in the database. The results are added at the same time so it seems strange to me that the event listener would get attached to one but not the other.

Comment: @MattAltepeter - if you are creating two divs (one edit area for each product) with id "mydiv", then that is why it's failing.

Comment: @ethorn10 could you recommend another way to do this then?

Comment: I changed it from `id='mydiv'` to `class='mydiv'` and it is still having the same issues

Comment: strange. I think it was actually a missing `</td>` that was causing the issue. I fixed that and it worked. Thanks for all of your help though!

Answer (score 1):

@Mortalus: The syntax you posted is for the regular direct event listener (not delegated events).

The delegated event listener syntax has an additional selector string between the event names and the event handler (using Matt's code as an example):

```
$(function() {
    $("table").on("click", ".edit_prod", function() {
        $("#mydiv").toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This means that any time an `.edit_prod` element inside a `table` is clicked that event handler will be invoked (even if more `.edit_prod` elements are added to the DOM later).